# weird console output of boolean value

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print out a boolean which represents whether it's a main thread, I tried:

```
let isMain = NSThread.isMainThread
print("result = \(isMain)")
```

But, console output is:

```
result = (Function)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isMainThread` is a function. This should work:

```
let isMain = NSThread.isMainThread()
print("result = \(isMain)")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a class function that returns whether or not the current thread is a function, which is what you've used, and a property on an `NSThread` object which you would access with:

```
let isMain = NSThread.currentThread().isMainThread
print("result = \(isMain)")
```